# Dataproc cluster are failing to install due to Error: Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, pypi

```
#Hi Please help I am new to stack overflow#
```

##**I am running GCP composer for my jobs one of the job is to create dataproc cluster .My dataproc cluster are failing to create.**##

```
**Error **

#Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` sine no key file is defined for hook.
```

_base_hook.py:145} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.#

Another error :
ERROR - <HttpError 409 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects//regions/us-east4/clusters?requestId=6c3f8806-176b-47=json returned "Already exists: Failed to create cluster: Cluster projects/project/regions/us-east4/clusters/ltvo-wkf-ltvo-sdm-it-dly". Details: "Already exists: Failed to create cluster .

```
  Initialization script which I have used : 

#!/bin/bash

set -exo pipefail

readonly PACKAGES=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/PIP_PACKAGES || true)

function err() {
  echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')]: $*" >&2
  exit 1
}

function run_with_retry() {
  local -r cmd=("$@")
  for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)); do
    if "${cmd[@]}"; then
      return 0
    fi
    sleep 5
  done
  err "Failed to run command: ${cmd[*]}"
}

function install_pip() {
  if command -v pip >/dev/null; then
    echo "pip is already installed."
    return 0
  fi

  if command -v easy_install >/dev/null; then
    echo "Installing pip with easy_install..."
    run_with_retry easy_install pip
    return 0
  fi

  echo "Installing python-pip..."
  run_with_retry apt update
  run_with_retry apt install python-pip -y
}

function main() {
  if [[ -z "${PACKAGES}" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Must specify PIP_PACKAGES metadata key"
    exit 1
  fi



  echo "Run local install..."
  #uri=gcp bucket/app_code/config/mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz
  #if [[ "${uri}" == gs://* ]]; then
  #  gsutil cp "${uri}" ./
  #  pip install ./mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz
  #else
  #  echo "Path is not gs://..."
  #fi

  #uri=gs<some gcs bucket>/app_code/config/protobuf-3.13.0.tar.gz
  #gsutil cp "${uri}" .

}
```

Comment: Please tidy up your question. It's very difficult to parse.

Comment: The script you include appears to include no obvious Google Cloud commands or scripts so it's of no use. It appears (!?) that your code is expecting [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#adc) with the `google.auth.default()` error . `google.auth.default()` is a Google Python library command that leverages ADC. The 409 error explains that it failed because the cluster already exists. If you want to create a new cluster, you will need to provide a different name.

Comment: Nice catch  but the scrip is already working fine , I am getting this error once in a week while rest of the day works fine without error.